# Formatting MySQL IF statement with date_format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL query, which is supposed to calculate the difference in time between the fields, but due to the query, i am unable to format it as a time through the interface, so its not calculating correctly, so I was trying to add the DATE_Format to the query, but no matter what I tried, nothing works.

Here is the query I am using:
`` IF(`Time Elapsed` < `Speed Fault`, `Speed Fault` - `Time Elapsed`, 0) AS `Under Time` , ``

I tried to add: `` DATE_FORMAT(`Under Time`, `%i:%s`) `` to the mix some how so the field will display the minutes and seconds.

Currently with the above query, its returning the correct amount of seconds, if the difference in under 60 seconds, but if its for example 3 minutes and 5 sec difference, the query returns a value of 305, as so on...

So i am hoping someone can help me out.  I am open to doing this in either PHP or MySQL.

Comment: You can't use an alias in the same query.

Comment: The first argument to `date_format()` has to be a datetime, not a number of seconds. You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert seconds to a `DATETIME`.

Comment: @Barmar - I don't have a value, its calculated on the fly from 2 other fields so i would have to put an alias in there for it to pull the correct information, wouldn't I?

Comment: You can put the query with the alias in a subquery, and then refer to the alias in the main query.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that @Barmar  What I am really just trying to figure our why when I am subtracting two time fields it doesn't give me the correct information back?

Comment: Please post the full query. I thought the problem was that you were trying to use the `Under Time` alias in the same query where you defined it.

Comment: What are the datatypes of `Time Elapsed` and `Speed Fault`?

Comment: the data types are time, and when I add the data it shows as `12:04:00 AM` but on the list/view page I have it formatted to show as `00:04:00` for both fields.  so for example using the formula above of the `under time` field, if `Time Elapsed = 00:03:00` and `Speed Fault = 00:04:30` a difference of 1:30, the result that would display in `Under Time = 70` I'm just not sure what is going on. @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Doing datestamp arithmetic is tricky. In MySQL, using DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data in a numerical context (for example by subtracting one from another) can get strange results.

I guess you want your results in a format like `1:23:45`, hours / minutes / seconds. In that case this is a job for [TIMEDIFF(later, earlier)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

```
IF(`Time Elapsed` < `Speed Fault`, 
   TIMEDIFF(`Speed Fault` - `Time Elapsed`),
   SEC_TO_TIME(0)) AS `Under Time`
```

If you want your results in seconds, use [TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, earlier, later)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and try this

```
 GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`Time Elapsed`, `Speed Fault`),0) AS `Under Time`
```

You probably noticed the  eariler / later parameters to the two functions are in opposite order. Database time arithmetic functions are like that.

And, be careful with formatted TIME data. It cannot show a time interval greater than or equal to 839 hours. If you try, it shows `838:59:59` without warning you.

Comment: Thanks I will try those two different pieces of code to see if it works the way I am looking for it to display.

Comment: So I tried the 2nd command and it works for displaying seconds, but I wanted to see how the IF command would work, and when I try it I receive the following error `Error executing query.  Fatal error:  Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'TIMEDIFF'` I've tried to change

Comment: Weird. AFAIK TIMEDIFF has just two parameters. But I've confused TIMESTAMPDIFF and TIMEDIFF multple times. Is that it?

Comment: I just tried it again using TIMESTAMPDIFF and get this error:

 MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`Speed Fault` - `Time Elapsed`), SEC_TO_TIME(0)) AS `Under Time` ,
`Over Time`,'

Comment: i've tried playing with the code and nothing I have tried works.